# Simple Question about Random Variable with Finite Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

> Consider a random variable $X$ with $E[X]< \infty$ and probability density $f_X$, I was wondering: 
>   given any positive number $\epsilon >0,$ do we always have
>   $$
>  \int_{-1/\epsilon}^\infty x f_X(x) dx \le  E[X]?
> $$

Here is my thinking: Given any $\epsilon >0, $
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{ - 1/\varepsilon }^\infty  x {f_X}(x)dx 
&= \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{1_{\{ x \ge - 1/\varepsilon \}}}x} {f_X}(x)dx
 \le ? \le  E[X]
\end{align}$$
It is tempting to say yes but my $X$ can take negative values; e.g., say $X$ is normal distributed, in this case I kind of stuck to argue further.

Comment: Direction of inequality should be reversed... $f_X$ is always non-negative, so for $x<0$, $xf_X$ is non-positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$ \begin{align*} E[X] & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx \\ 
& = \int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} xf_X(x)dx + \int_{-\epsilon}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx \\
& \leq \int_{-\epsilon}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx
\end{align*}$$

as the integrand $xf_X(x)$ is negative on $(-\infty, -\epsilon)$ as pointed out by others.